# Maximum characters printable by printf in C

Tags: c, string, printf, string-formatting

In C's printf function in using this gigantic string formatter width sub-specifier; close to the standard's limit a positive signed int; which is provided below the rest of the string formats are ignored.

Example String format:

```
printf("**%2147483614p %1073739618p This text and %d formatters are ignored!!! why**", &i, &j, 10);
```

output:
**`2147483614 empty spaces`0xbf****** `1073739618 empty spaces`

Problem:

The text "**This text and 10 formatters are ignored!!! why****" and the integer 10 does not show up on screen.
It prints the full of the first %p with its padding and the padding created by the width specifier for the second %p but no pointer and rest of string to be printed.

Note: the second pointer can be made to be printed by left adjusting the format specifier like

**printf("**%-2147483614p %-1073739618p This text and %d formatters are ignored!!! why**", &i, &j, 10);**

but still the strings after are still missing.

The code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    printf(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

x86_64-linux-gnu
gcc version 7.3.0

gcc printf.c -o printf

./printf "**%-2147483614p %-1073739618p This text and %d formatters are ignored!!! why**"

P.S. I am aware this is a memory leak

---

Found out %29p (29 is the max, 30 would not print) for second pointer prints the rest of the string. but if there is another format sting in the rest of the string it stops there.

Comment: `0x7ffffffe` is most likely not `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Please include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem . The exact code you used is important

Comment: INT_MAX is probably `0x7fffffff` on compiler with 32 bt integers

Comment: In addition to the code for the MVCE @M.M asks for you should indicate what platform you're running the test on and the compiler toolchain you're using.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the width value provided to a print format conversion specifier?

Comment: probably implementation dependent. Do you really want to print 1<<31 spaces on screen?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `1 << 31` is undefined behaviour (if int is 32-bit) so your comment is appropriate :D

Comment: `%D` is a non-standard conversion specification.

Comment: %D was an error i meant %d. Also i am redirecting stdout to a file

Comment: The program that's now in the question causes undefined behaviour since there are specifiers without corresponding arguments

Comment: Even if i give the arguments in the code still the behavior persists it is not the lack of string format arguments that is causing this.

Answer (score 8):

If you are asking specifically about the maximum width specifier, according to the **[C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf), §7.21.6.1.15** (which describes `fprintf`; `printf` is described later as a specific case of `fprintf`):

> The number of characters that can be produced by any single conversion shall be at least
>   4095.

This means that if, as you report, the maximum width that your C implementation's `printf` can handle for a format specifier before it stops working as expected is 0x7fffffe2, this is acceptable, since that satisfies the requirement of at least 4095 characters.

As for the remainder of the string not being printed out, without an MCVE, I would hazard a guess at it being a side effect of having such nonsensical width values earlier in the string. Also, `%D` is not a valid format specifier.

Comment: From your quote of the standard, I would expect `"%4095p"` to print out the value of the pointer padded out to 4095 bytes. Your statement *you are not guaranteed that anything else will get converted for that format specifier* seems to imply the pointer value might not get printed.

Comment: Upvoted, but using any value greater than 4095 results in undefined behavior. So, all bets are off in terms of what `printf` will do.

Comment: @jxh using a value greater than 4095 does not result in undefined behaviour. The environmental limits pertain to whether an implementation is conforming or not; they are not conditions on a program

Comment: @M.M What is a conforming implementation to do with a program that attempts to emit more than the environmental limits allow?

Comment: @jxh the standard is not completely clear but my interpretation is that `fprintf` should return a negative error code if it could not correctly perform the output due to an environmental limit.  Some of the other library environmental limits do specify what happens if the limit is exceeded (e.g. `setjmp` specifically says that it is UB to exceed the limit).  It certainly does not use wording like "a program shall not request a conversion that would produce more than 4095"

Comment: @M.M: I had always operated under the assumption that if the standard had defined behavior for the acceptable input, and did not define behavior for unacceptable input, the behavior for processing unacceptable input was undefined. Are you saying that violation of environmental limits does not constitute unacceptable input? Or is it that the program is conforming so long as there is a single conforming implementation that accepts it? Hmmm...

Comment: @jxh yes. The definition of the behaviour of field width modifier doesn't have any limitation on the value of the modifier. The environmental limits pertain to the implementation, not the program.  A program that exceeds this limit is not *strictly conforming* but that doesn't mean it causes UB